# CSS does not resize (Mozilla Firefox)

Tags: html, css

using CSS Flex I wish to visualise 3 static elements horizontally, and then underneath one of a selection of images, which could be of different sizes, widths, heights. I wish to use all the vertical space available for the image and adjust the width automatically to ensure the whole image is shown with no overflow.
My solution correctly resizes for Chrome and Edge, but always shows the maximum width for Firefox.
Any ideas how to get round this? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="./test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer-container">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="leftslide"  id="previous"><</div>
            <div class="centername"><p id="placeNameImage"></p></div>
            <div class="rightslide" id="next">></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliderimages" id="actualImage">
            <img id="y" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var url = "vaio.jpg";
        document.getElementById("placeNameImage").innerHTML = "image =  " + url;
        document.getElementById('y').src = url;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code test.css is below:

```
.outer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* stack 'slider' above 'sliderimages' */
    height: 98vh; 
    background-color: #e6ffff; /* very light blue */
}

.outer-container .slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* elements stacked horizontally */
    justify-content: space-between; 
    height: 30px; 
    border: 2px solid  #29a8e2; /* shade of blue  */
    background-color: #ffffe6 /* very light yellow */
}

.outer-container .slider .centername {
    color: #0000cc;  /* dark blue */
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.outer-container .slider .leftslide,.outer-container .slider .rightslide { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px; 
    line-height: 30px; /* centre of arrow */
    background-color: #444444; /* black */
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#ffffff; /* white */
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.outer-container .slider .leftslide:hover,.outer-container .slider .rightslide:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    background-color: #29a8e2; /* shade of blue */
}

.outer-container .slider .leftslide {
    left: 30px;
    top: 10px;
}

.outer-container .slider .rightslide {
    right: 30px;
    top: 10px;
}

.outer-container .sliderimages {
    max-height: calc(98vh - 30px - 2px - 2px);
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.outer-container .sliderimages img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The image used was called "vaio.jpg" but I was unable to upload it.
Any image will do as long as its resolution is over 800x800 px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: prevent the image from stretching horizontally & center align it

```
.outer-container .sliderimages {
    display: flex;
    /*[...]*/
    justify-content: center;
}

.outer-container .sliderimages img {
    align-self: start;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/scheinercc/pen/OJZayMG

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. While it does give the correct width in a large window in Firefox, unfortunately the image does not resize properly, neither in Firefox nor Chrome nor Edge. Before Edge and Chrome resized correctly.

Comment: @nexturejohn - I have updated my example above. tested in Firefox, Chrome and Safari (Edge is just another Chromium and should render same as Chrome)

Comment: retrovertigo: thank you, this has solved the problem! Thanks again!